# SQL Trigger does not work

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-delete

Are there any conditions in which a Trigger is not fired?

We have this situation:

We have a table and there are rows that are been deleted. We need to know who and/or when these row are deleted.

We create this trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AUDITdel_nit] ON [dbo].[Client]
 FOR DELETE
 AS
 Insert into AUDIT select 'Delete', getdate(), 'Row Deleted', SYSTEM_USER, host_name(),
 (select 'ID Client: ' + convert(varchar(12),Id)  from deleted), 'Client' ,APP_NAME()
```

We made some test: deleting rows via stored procedures and the deleted rows appears in our AUDIT table.

But suddenly today we found a row deleted that does not appear in the AUDIT table...

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: What RDMS are you using (it looks like SQL Server given the "GETDATE()" call).

Comment: It's not the cause of your problem, but your current trigger code doesn't deal with multi-row deletes (they'll cause an error in your trigger, which will then rollback the change)

Comment: Can you add the table definitions for dbo.Client and AUDIT please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it handle multiple record deletes which it currently cannot do.  All triggers must always be written assuming that multiple records will be deleted, inserted or updated.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AUDITdel_nit] ON [dbo].[Client]  
FOR DELETE  AS  

INSERT INTO AUDIT 
SELECT 'Delete', getdate(), 'Row Deleted', SYSTEM_USER, host_name(),  
         'ID Client: ' + convert(varchar(12),Id) , 'Client' ,APP_NAME() 
FROM DELETED
```

Bulk inserts can also bypass a trigger and truncate table does not involve triggers as the actions aren't logged, but I think these are not your issue here.  Openrowset statements can also be run to ignore triggers.  You can search your code for this phrase to see if a process is doing that: WITH(IGNORE_TRIGGERS). You can also specifically disable and re-enable a trigger but no one on production should have the rights to do that except dbas.  If everyone has those rights, you need to fix that ASAP.

Comment: but with the trigger as they've currently got it, they're selecting from deleted within a subquery - so if it's a multi-row delete, they'll get an error about multiple results from a subquery. That's why I said it wasn't likely to be the actual problem.

Comment: But it's not a correlated query so they may not, I'd have to test to see. In any event it is irresponsible not to fix this.

Comment: Well... Thanks.. We'll work in the trigger so it can handle several deleted rows.
But actually only 1 row is deleted... So the actual trigger should handle it, no?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your trigger is not invalidated ?

```
SELECT * FROM   ALL_OBJECTS WHERE  OBJECT_NAME = 'your_trigger' AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'TRIGGER' AND STATUS <> 'VALID'
```

Comment: Thanks Ricko.. In MS SQL I dnot find status column!

Answer (score 0):

I think insert statement after deletion didn't work. So you can check why the audit insert fails.

```
Insert into AUDIT select 'Delete', getdate(), 'Row Deleted', SYSTEM_USER, host_name(),
(select 'ID Client: ' + convert(varchar(12),Id)  from deleted), 'Client' ,APP_NAME()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using triggers, is there a possibility that some changes to the clients table are caused by other triggers, and the `nested triggers` option is set to 0? This isn't the default setup, but it would result in your trigger not firing in this case. A demonstration of the effect is below. To see whether this option has been set, just run `sp_configure` with no parameters, and find the `nested triggers` row.

```
sp_configure 'nested triggers','0'
go
reconfigure
go
create table T3 (
    ID int not null
)
go
create table T2 (
    ID int not null
)
go
create trigger T_T2
on T2
for insert
as
    insert into T3(ID) select ID from inserted
go
create table T1 (
    ID int not null
)
go
create trigger T_T1
on T1
for insert
as
    insert into T2(ID) select ID from inserted
go
insert into T1(ID)
select 1
go
select * from T1
select * from T2
select * from T3
```

Messages & Results:

```
Configuration option 'nested triggers' changed from 1 to 0. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.

(1 row(s) affected)

ID
----
1
(1 row(s) affected)

ID
----
1
(1 row(s) affected)

ID
----
(0 row(s) affected)
```